# How should I design my database for different user has different devices?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I was confused about database design.

This is my request: There are different users; a user can has one or more devices. Some users will have thousands devices even ten thousand devices. A device has many operation records. One day adds 10-20 operation records.

I prepare to create a table for user record userId, passWord. A different user creates different device list table record deviceNum, devicState. A device has a operation table record operation records.

So,  my database will have many many tables. I guess I have more one hundred thousand devices. Should I create one hundred thousand devices tables?

Comment: Can a Device be used by multiple users or only one?  are the operations unique to a device? or could the same operation occur on multiple devices with different values?

Comment: P.lease share rough / tentative table structures of the 3 tables that you mentioned above. It'll easier to comprehend from it rather than text. I'll be able to share detailed insights then.

Comment: BTW, I suggest you only store some *passWordHash*, not a plain *passWord*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you've said you need 3 tables only:

```
Users - user_id, username, pass, data, etc...
Devices - device_id, user_id (owner), device_data....
OpRecords - record_id, device_id, record_data_stuff...
```

All users go to the first table with additional fields you need for user data like address, phone, last login time, etc.

All devices are registered into the `Devices` table with each device having association to the user who owns it - the user_id. You can make as much columns as needed - like device type, device name, parameters, workhours and so on...

All records go to a single table and record is associated with the device that did the job (device_id). You can make your additional columns here to write record-specific data like start_time, end_time, and so on...

You don't need to have a separate table for the record list of each device. When you need to show the records of a single device just make `SELECT` with `device_id = X` and you will receive the records for your device only.

UPDATE:

> ten thousand devices ,everyone make ten operation records one day .ten
>   days

It makes about 1 million records for 10 days. It is a chalange. But I don't think splitting this data into different tables will give you a better performance.

You should set as minimum columns in the `records` table as possible. Place there the minimum required information. Try not to use strings and if possible use only integer numbers. If you use fields to write date/time use TIMESTAMP as it is closest to integer number. Create indexes on all columns you will use to search data - device_id, time (if you have such column) an so on. This will increase disk usage but I think will raise the performance.

Consider if you can backup your data to external file after a given period - in example after a month you would free 3 million records.

Comment: All devices is operation record save one table.Is that will make operation table too big ? ten thousand devices ,everyone make ten operation records one day .ten days I will have one hundred operation records.Is that will make select be hard?

Comment: Actually,it doesn't have ten thousand devices in this year,but would be.I think I need use hash key to make sql partition.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a layout like this:

```
User
+----+----------+----------+-------+
| id | username | password | email |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | jon      | xxxx     | xxxx  |
|  2 | melissa  | xxxx     | xxxx  |
+----+----------+----------+-------+

Device
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id |  name  |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | iPad   |
|  2 |       1 | iPhone |
|  3 |       1 | Laptop |
|  4 |       2 | Laptop |
+----+---------+--------+

Operation
+----+-----------+-----+-------+
| id | device_id | key | value |
+----+-----------+-----+-------+
|  1 |         1 | x   | y     |
|  2 |         1 | y   | z     |
|  3 |         2 | x   | x     |
|  4 |         2 | z   | y     |
|  5 |         3 | x   | y     |
+----+-----------+-----+-------+
```

I hope that I got your question right.

Comment: About Operation table ,ten thousand devices ,every device will make ten operation records one day .That mean Operation table will add one hundred thousand operation records every day .Is that to much?